# Are methods in classes using the 'Curiously Recurring Template Pattern' inlined by a modern c++ compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, crtp

I have a performance critical piece of code for which I am considering using the CRTP. My question is to what extent most compilers are able to optimize the code. In particular I am wondering if the compiler can inline (when appropriate) methods. For example, in the following code:

```
template <class Derived> 
struct Base
{
    void interface()
    {
        // ...
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->implementation();
        // ...
    }
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    void implementation();
};
```

would a call to `object.interface()` yield the same performance as a call to `object.implementation()`

Comment: Performance questions are really pretty pointless here. If it matters to you, examine the assembler output of your compiler - compilers can effectively inline (or not) what they like.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: I generally agree with you, except that performance questions involving a particular algorithms or languages that don't have several implementations or good optimizers are fairly reasonable. For example, I've gotten some excellent answers about CPython performance issues, and I've seen some good questions about algorithm performance.

Comment: @Omnif Algorithms don't have performance - implementations of them do. And at that point, we are back to the question being implementation specific (of the algorithm, of its use and of the compiler/language system).

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: If that's the case, then what's the point of O notation?

Comment: @Omnif O notation says nothing about performance, only complexity. It's trivial to provide an implementation of an O(1) algorithm which is slower than an O(N) one.

Comment: Just to be clear. the question is whether the compiler can optimize away the cast and pointer dereference. I'm not really sure how to look at assembly, so I was hoping that the wisdom of SO could help.

Comment: @Ian Learning the basics of assembly language for your platform (you need to be able to read it enough to get the basic drift, not to be able to write a complete app in it) is A Good Idea, IMHO. I can't imagine not being able to do it, in fact. To answer your question - can the compiler optimise things away? Sure. Will it, and has it? You need to read the compiler output.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth - I do not think anybody outside of CS cares about complexity apart from performance. Yet they still use O notation to describe algorithms. Are you trying to tell me that asking for a better performing sort than a bubble sort is an 'optimization' problem and therefore will not get a good answer and that that answer will not talk about O notation?

Comment: @Omnif Well, if they don't care about complexity, they shouldn't use O notation. There is no guarantee that a bubble sort will be slower than (say) quicksort (in many cases it may be faster), and O notation says nothing about this.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: So there is no useful correlation between O notation and performance? If so, why doesn't everybody use the fast bubblesort?

Comment: @Omnif No, there is no correlation - a bubblesort really is typically faster than a quicksort if the number of elements is small or (for a naive quicksort implementation) if they are already in order. You can't use O notation to *generally* select your algorithm - you have to know what you are doing and/or whether you care about performance that much. Most people don't, and shouldn't, and so a  quicksort (or one of the modern variants) is perfectly fine. But this has nothing to do with O notation.

Comment: Sorry, "generally" should probably be its opposite "specifically" in the above comment. The sense of the comment (and the others) remains - O notation says nothing about performance, only about complexity.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: I will now start telling everybody that the complexity of an algorithm has no performance implications and should not be considered when asking questions about the performance of an algorithm. Unfortunately, I imagine that will make the task of interviewing for a job much harder. Also, if there are no performance implications based on complexity, the sort implementation in modern STL libraries should be replaced with bubblesort to reduce the chances of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With optimization turned on, and if the compiler considers this to be worth inlining, yes.

What's good in CRTP compared to dynamic dispatch, is that from compiler's point of view it's a regular function call.

Comment: I am aware that it has the advantage of not requiring a virtual table look-up, but I am wondering whether the entire body of interface gets optimized away. i.e. the function call and pointer dereference.

Comment: @Ian: I've not talked about virtual tables. Please, understand my words literally: "from compiler's point of view it's a regular function call" which implies that it can do, and will do, any optimizations as it does with regular function calls. So your question about CRTP reduces to the question "when your compiler inlines regular function calls".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I can then infer form your answer that (with optimization on), calls to interface and implementation are treated identically by the compiler. Is this correct?

Comment: @Ian: Yes. Btw, if the interface is merely a tiny wrapper that forwards the call to the implementation, then it's more likely that the *interface* will be inlined at the call site, rather than the implementation into the interface.

Answer (score 4):

Overwhelmingly probably. Of course, there's only one way to be sure.